# Storing connection string as a global variable which was retrieved from appsettings.json - ASP.NET Core 3.1

Tags: asp.net-core

Currently I store the connection string in `appsettings.json` and assigning that value to a static variable on startup.

appsettings.json

```
{
    "ConnectionString": {
        "MasterDB": "Data Source=XXXXXXX; initial catalog=XXX;user id=XX; password=XXXXXXX",
    },
}
```

`Startup.cs`:

```
// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    }

    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseRouting();

    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseAuthorization();

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });

    MASTER_DB_CONNECTION_STRING = Configuration.GetValue<string>("ConnectionString:MasterDB");
}
```

My goal is to have a connection string variable which can be used to perform CRUD operations and does not like to use the configuration class to retrieve the connection string every time (using Dapper.NET).

But, this method does not feel right, please advice on how to improve this. And is it okay to declare custom variables in `startup.cs`?

Further, how can I restrict the said variable so that it can not be changed on runtime after the first initialization?

Comment: [Options pattern in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-6.0)

Comment: in my humble opinion, it's good to get connection string from appsetting.json directly. And if you think storing connection string is not secure, then you may store it in somewhere like Azure key vault.... No need to set a global variable to read the appsetting file first..